# Django objects filter to search both unique and combined fields with exclusivity

Tags: python, django, object, search

I am trying to create a search function for a Django query set, which is able to search by unique keywords but also have exclusivity.

For example, if I search 'John' I would like all Johns returned, if I search 'Smith' I would like all the Smiths returned, but if I search 'John Smith', I only want 'John Smith(s)' returned.

I have tried several methods:

**Attempt 1 - views.py**

This only returns results with an identical keyword. i.e. returns all John's or Smith's only, but search John Smith returns nothing:

```
if query:
    data = Profile.objects.filter(
        Q(first_name__icontains=query) | Q(last_name__icontains=query) |
        Q(username__username__icontains=query) | Q(email__icontains=query) |
        Q(telephone__icontains=query) | Q(mobile__icontains=query) |
        Q(job_title__icontains=query) | Q(department__icontains=query) |
        Q(address__address__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
```

**Attempt 2 - views.py**

This returns all John's and Smith's, and searching John Smith still returns all John's and Smith's.

```
if query:
    search = []
    query_set = query.split()
    for word in query_set:
    search = Profile.objects.filter(
            Q(first_name__icontains=word) | Q(last_name__icontains=word) |
            Q(username__username__icontains=word) | Q(email__icontains=word) |
            Q(telephone__icontains=word) | Q(mobile__icontains=word) |
            Q(job_title__icontains=word) | Q(department__icontains=word) |
            Q(address__address__icontains=word)
        ).distinct()
    data = list(set(search))
```

Are there any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching using `__icontains` in your filter. This will return all objects containing the string that you specify, case insensitive. So John will return true for John, john, JoHn, John Smith, Johnny or any object that contains any version of John.

You would need to implement a separate query that uses `__exact` or `__iexact`. This will give you the exclusivity search you are looking for. So if you search for John Smith using `__exact__`, only objects with John Smith will be returned, case sensitive. If you use `__iexact__`, John Smith, john smith, John smith or any object containing John Smith regardless of case will return True. Johnny Smith would not return True for either of the `__exact__` or `__iexact` queries in this case.

I'm not sure what your application entails but this use case would be a perfect implementation for a filter in the front end.

So your query would change from `Q(first_name__icontains=word)` to `Q(first_name__exact=word)` or `Q(first_name__iexact=word)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. Unfortunately, that didn't help. My solution was instead to search first name and last name for each word in the query, and if both match, then I return only the dual match, but if only one matches, then I return all matches.

Comment: All good. Glad you came right.